# here is my code to delete a specific value from firebase database but not working

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database structure:

[image]

```
//Read the single value
mPrizeRef.child("prize").equalTo(mVal);
mPrizeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Value= " + dataSnapshot1.child("prize").getValue(String.class));
            prizeList.add(dataSnapshot1.child("prize").getValue().toString());
            String club = dataSnapshot1.getKey().toString();
            mPrizeRef.child(dataSnapshot1.getKey()).removeValue();
        }

        if (prizeList.size() > 0) {
            Random random = new Random();
            mVal = prizeList.get(random.nextInt(prizeList.size())).toString();
            mText.setText(prizeList.get(random.nextInt(prizeList.size())).toString());
        }
}
```

Here is my code to delete a specific value from firebase database but not working. But the value is generated by a random function the key of the value is stored in club variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android how to remove value from firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176099/android-how-to-remove-value-from-firebase-database)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to delete a v

```
     dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
```

You should also check if the value isn't null

```
     if(snapshot.child("msg").getValue() != null){
        String msg = snapshot.child("msg").getValue().toString();
        return;
     }
```