# How to show items from two children in one RecyclerView from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is image representation of my firebase where user upload items under Electronics or Books category and also more categories. I want to build an activity with `RecyclerView` where I want to show the only item uploaded by a user. Since I'm using `userid` which is unique to push the details of the item inside a child, I can use `userid` to retrieve the items from child and display in firebase. But, how to search in each child from different category and show it in one `RecyclerView`.

[image]

My Code to Show the items from Electronics child is

```
dbreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Electronic").child("userid");

dbreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
         for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            final Solditem b1 = data.getValue(SoldItem.class);

            child_count++;
            list.add(b1);
            staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    }
}
```

But I also would like to show the uploaded item by a user which equals to `userid` as key from Books in the same `RecyclerView`.

To delete an item from any category I use

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query sellerquery = ref.child("Electronic").child("userid");

sellerquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }
}
```

To delete all the records of a user-uploaded item which key-value equals to `userid`, I need to repeat above code.

Is there any best and short method to delete all the records from any category which key-value equals to `userid`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While structuring your data in Firebase, you really need to think about the structure of your data very carefully so that you can run efficient queries on them. For example, in your case, you should have structured your data as follows.

```
userid
    - Electronics
        - Camera
        - Cooker
    - Books
        - A brief history of time
        - Inferno
```

Hence you could run your queries in such a way that, you could have all the items under a certain `userid` at once.

If you really need the structure that you have now for other sets of queries that you are planning to do in your application, think about replicating your data as well. That is, you might consider having duplicate entries of your data (replication) in different structure so that you can perform efficient queries. For example, the current structure of your data is suitable for the following query.

> Get all userid under a specific category.

I think you have got my point. If you do not want to change the structure of your data then I am afraid that you might have to get all the data in your application from firebase first. Then you have to loop through the data yourself to find the elements that you actually needed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Raez I get some idea just small query  , If I want to show all the elctronics item under Electronic Category from all users in an recycleview ..How can I show that?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the way you have put your data is suitable for the query - "If I want to show all the elctronics item under Electronic Category from all users in an recycleview". Hence for your other query which is - "show all the items from all categories for a specific user", you need to create another node. Where the data will be structured as I have mentioned in my answer. Yes, you will have duplicate data in your database, however, this is good for efficiency.

Comment: Problem I'm facing is while deleting any itme that is being sold...that means I have write same code two times with differenet child refrence to delete same item from node you have suggested from user profile and from node I have created to remove it from there.....is there any other way....like to delete item from all records which userid equalto so current userid instead of writing same code twice with different child refrence?

Comment: If you have replicated data, yes, you need to delete the data from two different child reference. Which is not very expensive if you have organized your data in correct way. In my opinion, deleting an item from a category is easy. Just get the reference of your category node then `ref.child(categoryName).child(userid).child(itemToBeRemoved).removeValue()`, should suffice. And from the `userid` node, get the reference for the `user` node first, then `userRef.child(userid).child(categoryName).child(itemToBeRemoved).removeValue()` should suffice right? You do not have to use a loop here I guess.

Comment: writing this two line of code would be very easy..should I also need to specigy value event listener for both as I have stated in my second code in above queston..that will same repeated code huge if I have to write as above since I'll have 30-35 categories....but if writing only one line is enough then..It is impressive but if I have to write as above it will occupy huge space of same code

Comment: I think these two lines should suffice. Again, as I do not know about the whole purpose of your application, your implementation might vary. But I think, you have got the idea.

Comment: Okay thanks Reaz a lot for clear explanations...One last thing why value event listener is added if only a single line of code is suffificent to remove a value..since I followed some tutorial and copied above code to use in my applicaton.......is it necesary to add value event listener but instead only write one line of code as you have suggested ? How will user will get notice that data has been deleted if no events listener is attached?

Comment: I don't know about the examples that you had looked into. However, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40176158/3145960) which tells me that one line is sufficient. Please note that, after removing a value from your database, you might need to update your `RecyclerView` accordingly as you do not have the values that you had before right? Hence the `ValueEventListener` comes in handy.

Comment: Umm I guess even if data is deleted from firebase....if valueevent listener is not attached, the information will be displayed to user untill if there is anyother way to refresh the recycleview and show the recent changed list

Comment: You are right. Hence the `ValueEventListener` comes in handy. Great to know that you have understood the problem and the solution. :)

Comment: Yes reaz I understood now...so is there any other way to refresh recycleview and load current changed data if valueevent listener is not attached then?.should I refresh the activity and reload?

Comment: You should not reload or refresh your activity. Just have a `public ValueEventListener` attached to your database references, which will update the values automatically when a value is deleted. You do not have to do anything by yourself. The `ValueEventListener`s will track the changes of your reference points and will update the list when there is some change/deletion.

Comment: so my question was same attaching a value event listener for each refrences will then amount in large amount of code of many lines..so If there was any way to minimize the code....and you suggested to simply write in one line....but if I skip the valueevent listener method then update value won't be displayed to user even if data is changed..so if there was any way to update recycleview if valueevent listener is  not used....? But if there is no other way then let it be i'll use valueevent listener for each refrences..and I think there is no other way then

Comment: I have multiple categories...like electornics, book ,furtniture, clothes and +55 more so...if user press delete button I wanted to remove the form whole database

Comment: Actually, a single database reference for all these is sufficient here. Because once you get the reference of the parent node which holds all the categories, you can easily iterate through all the categories by `ref.child(categoryName)`. If you do not have the category names beforehand, just try adding a simple loop to get all the categories first in an `ArrayList`. This will help you for easier referencing to those nodes, right?

Comment: Okay I'll try ...and thanks for such nice and kind comments...It really help me a lot to understand in more depth.